# Is it possible to cut/filter all layers to an area of interest in one step?

Tags: qgis

The problem of working with a lot of data (about 100 layers). Very slow computer, rendering long.

Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Clip a very good tool, but replace the 100 layers is very high and can go wrong. In addition to work with the same data in different regions, and each time the clip function is complicated work.

Is there a faster way, and saves computer resources?

On ArcView GIS 3.2 is called the "Area of interest" or Autocad Map 3D "query to filter date".

Comment: What you use for your data source ? NAd far as i know QGIS tries to read only data in view so it already does "clipping". If you use postGIS or spatial lite datasource you can limit data using ST_intersect(geom, "bounding box of your definition" ) ) ( which dosen't solve your problem with 100 layers)

Comment: So far, using the "Show Bookmarks". It is also a good way to "Scale dependent visibility" (Layer -> Properties -> General), but how to do all or selected layers in one step?

Comment: you "can" select all layers using shift or ctrl and then properties, but i dont know does it really affect all layers or not. But that is easy to test. 
If QGIS project is xml , you could try to do find and replace in text editor

Comment: "select all layers using shift or ctrl and then properties" does not work. selecting still give change only one layer. It would be easy and convenient.

Comment: "replace in text editor" - yes it's possible, but the average consumer will not be able to. We organize free courses QGIS users, and I know that this will be difficult.

Comment: average user is happy to use what ever works , even it means that he has to click 100 times some magic compo. The Problem user in this case is "power users" who know that there should be easier way. Which gave me an idea . Try use python script :http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49346/how-do-i-use-qgis-python-console-to-iterate-through-simple-layer-queries-and-png seems to be good example.